# Prevent loss of variables

Tags: c#, javascript, pageload

I am passing values generated in C# to my Javascript function like -

**C#**

```
 protected int Month;
 protected int Day;
 protected int Minute;
 protected int Hour;

 // set these later in code
```

**Aspx**

```
function test() {

                  Month: '<%= Month%>'
                  Day: '<%= Day%>'
                  Minute: '<%= Minute%>'
                  Hour: '<%= Hour%>'
```

However as the page reloads when various controls are hit, these variables are being reset to empty. Is there a way I can keep these values so that they are not lost on reload?

Comment: Your aspx.cs file needs to set those variables with every load - including postbacks.

Comment: That is because http is stateless

Comment: Define `"set these later in code"`.  When the page reloads, do you "set these" again?

Comment: @David so for instance Month = 01; would be set on a button click etc.

Comment: @Ebikeneser: Can you expand the code sample in the question to include that?  If the values are empty when the page renders then it would appear that they're not being set in a post back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just define all your fields as properties with values stored in the `ViewState`, like the example below for `Month`:

```
protected int Month
{
    get { return this.ViewState["Month"] != null ? (int)this.ViewState["Month"] : 0; }
    set { this.ViewState["Month"] = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the values to a hidden field or some other control on the page that will maintain the value through a page load (through viewstate)